# No images through nginx-proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, ansible, keep-alive, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm setting up a VPS via ansible to run a web app that's already in a docker container. That part is up and running. Moving on to the proxy part, I added `jwilder/nginx-proxy` and `jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion` to my playbook. In general that is working. The SSL cert were created, and I can access the web app through the proxy. Unfortunately the images don't seem to be getting through. I think I need to tweak the "Connection" to be "keep-alive". Though I've yet to figure out how to get that set. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

nginx-proxy env vars:

```
  VIRTUAL_HOST: "{{ webserver_hostname }}"
  VIRTUAL_PORT: 9000
  LETSENCRYPT_HOST: "{{ webserver_hostname }}"
  LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: "{{ letsencrypt_email }}"
  SSL_POLICY: Mozilla-Modern
```

docker images in use:

- jwilder/nginx-proxy
- jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
- custom docker with app.

Note:

- I have removed the letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion and the image
  problem remains.
- I don't have problems with the images if I directly access the port on web app's docker.

Browser responses:

- Safari:

  - "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost."
  - Error: "The network connection was lost."
- Chrome:

  - Status is "(failed)".
  - Checking the response header the status is 200.
  - Under the timing, Connection Start is "Stalled".
- Firefox:

  - Status is 200, but Response payload is empty.

Thanks again for taking a look.